# Should i again generate "Signedapk" after made changes to code

Tags: android, signed-apk

For upload my application on google playstore. I have generated signedapk so my question is after made few changes in code of the app Shall i generate signed apk again ?

Comment: Yes..for the first time while signing APK file you got a keystore..use the same keystore to signed the APK each time while updating apk to playstore

Comment: yes of course ,if you want those changes to be shown to user than you have to generate new apk

Comment: ohk i got it and where i have to store that jks file ? @SantoshKathait

Comment: @BrindaRathod while signing the apk for second time it will ask weather  to create new keystore or use the old one, then select the old keystore by selecting the complete path of keystore and use the old password that has been used for keystore while signing APK for the first time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes.**

You done some changes in your code.
if you want your changes generate apk. 
There is no other way to do.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely. before uploading application to the Play Store, you should always generate signed APK.

It would be better if you do it with ProGuard, it will provide security to your application.

There are several other things to taken care of while generating signed apk.

- Proguard
- Enable Minify
- Shrink Resources
- String Localization
- Turn off Logging and Debugging
- Delete unused files
- Change Version Name and Version Code

Test your application throughout after doing all these things, there are chances that some things might not work after enabling `Proguard` and `shrink resources`. So its better to solve them and build apk again.

For more information, you can visit this link. 
https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's **mandatory** to resign the APK whenever you want to regenerate the app, otherwise the application will not be updated if you are using Google Play

https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html

Comment: kk I got it !  Thanks